# Configuração WebView passo a passo

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação HTML5 para dispositivos *mobile*. Inicialmente usei ferramentas como Adobe PhoneGab Build e App Inventor. Por motivos de projetos futuros, tenho que usar o Android Studio. O problema é que tanto a documentação oficial quando a comunidade tem a cultura de jogar os códigos em suas páginas de tutoriais, assumindo que o desenvolvedor saiba a correta implementação de tais códigos (que não é o meu caso). Alguns podemos deduzir pela sintaxe, como por exemplo um Java ou um XML. Mais raramente estes tutoriais apontam o caminho ou arquivo para inserção. Se é no `ActiveMain`, no `AndroidManifest`, etc.

Até cheguei a encontrar alguns tutoriais com o caminho exato de **alguns** dos códigos (embora não informem o `mWebView.loadUrl`, o mais importante). Sim, eu já cheguei a baixar exemplos "prontos", mas nunca chegam no *make*, sempre dão erro. Procurei exaustivamente. Talvez eu não esteja buscando as palavras chaves certas.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma solução passo a passo, para rodar minha aplicação HTML5 nativamente em um `.apk` Android, com os arquivos dentro do dispositivo, sem barra de URL, JavaStript habilitado, *fullscreen*, etc. Se leu até aqui, agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navegando pela internet, encontrei uma solução no site de desenvolvedores do google chrome. O link está em inglês, mas está bastante compreensível mesmo para quem não domina o idioma. Encontrado no link: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted

Um pequeno resumo:

Introdução -> Primeiro, instale corretamente o Android Studio.
    Instalando primeiro JDK SE para seu sistema operacional, seja
    MAC/Linux/Windows. Em seguida instale o Android Studio. Crie um
    projeto do tipo "Em branco" (Empty Activy ou Blanck Activy
    dependendo da sua versão). Importante não dar nomes aos pacotes. Apenas ir avançando, para iniciantes.

O tutorial vai dar uma apresentada na estrutura de projetos em Android Studio. Ache o arquivo `activity_main.xml` encontrado em

> app > res > layout >  activity_main.xml

Algumas versões ou tipos de projetos do Android Studio vai estar com a marcação `<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` ou `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` dentro do arquivo `activity_main.xml`.

Deverá ser adcionado este código no arquivo:

```
 <WebView
         android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Agora vamos ao arquivo MainActivity.java (importante não ter nomeado o pacote em fase de aprendizado). Encontrado em:

> app > java > com.nomedoprojeto.projeto > MainActivity.java

Agora vem uma parte delicada se não está acostumado com java.

Substitua este código:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
```

Por este:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

Lembra quando você estava aprendendo JAVA, e na aula dizia que como ela ser OOP, tudo era quase sempre necessário criar tanto classes quanto pacotes? Pois então... o objeto webview e a variável mWebview vai estar marcado de vermelho pois não estão se referindo a nada ainda. Passe o mouse em cima, e clique em cima da solução rápida do Android Studio, geralmente representada por uma lâmpada ou a primeira opção. Vai ter uma caixinha explicando a solução do seu S.O. Faça o que ela mandar. Geralmente é alt+enter.

No mesmo arquivo antes das chaves finais, adicione isso para ativar o javascript:

```
// Enable Javascript
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Vai aparecer o mesmo probleminha das marcações em vermelho. Repita o procedimento.
E finalmente, ainda no mesmo arquivo, adicione a URL do site que quer abrir:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
```

Agora, para finalizar, adicione a permissão de acesso a internet no `AndroidManifest.xml` do android encontrado em:

> app > manifests > AndroidManifest.xml

Adicione este código depois do `</aplication>`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Re-explicar esse tutorial foi mais difícil do que fazer o feito. Aproveitem!